# Deform/Colander validator that has access to all nodes?

Tags: python, pyramid, deform, colander

How do you define a custom validator in Deform/Colander that has access to
all node values. I need to access the values from two fields in order to decide if a particular value is valid or not?

Answer (score 3):

To place a validator for all colander fields we can simply do this

**validator method:**

```
def user_DoesExist(node,appstruct):
if DBSession.query(User).filter_by(username=appstruct['username']).count() > 0:
    raise colander.Invalid(node, 'Username already exist.!!')
```

**Schema:**

```
class UserSchema(CSRFSchema):
username = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), description="Extension of the user")
name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), description='Full name')
extension = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),description='Extension')
pin = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), description='PIN')
```

**View:**

```
@view_config(route_name='add_user', permission='admin', renderer='add_user.mako')
def add_user(self):
    #Here you can provide validator method as a parameter. And you can validate any field you want.
    schema = UserSchema(validator = user_DoesExist).bind(request=self.request)
    form = deform.Form(schema, action=self.request.route_url('add_user'), buttons=('Add User','Cancel'))
```

Correct me if i am wrong in my scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Tangibly the answer is:

```
def verify_email_validator(form, values):
    if values['email_address'] != values['verify_email']:
        raise Invalid(form, 'Email values do not match')

class MySchema(MappingSchema):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KickEntrySchema, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.validator=verify_email_validator  # entire form validator

    email_address = SchemaNode(Email())
    verify_email = SchemaNode(Email())
```

Note the form validator is invoked only if none of the individual field validators raise an error.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you bind MySchema  to a form in a view i.e. deform.Form(MySchema().bind(), buttons=('Submit', 'Cancel'), ....). Tim Hoffman's solution works and worth clicking as it proposes just passing a keyword parameter instead of overriding a method.